# how do I know if boost::regex_replace made a change?

Tags: c++, boost

In perl, I can do this

```
if($str =~ s/a/b/) {
  do something
}
```

In c++, I know how to do the search/replace part:

```
str = boost::regex_replace(str, boost::regex("a"), "b",  
                           boost::match_default | boost::format_perl ) ;
```

How do I know if any replacement was done?

I could compare the old to the new value. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better way of doing this, but I cannot see any hints for that in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html). The function seem to format and/or copy input to the output. So the straight forward solutions would be something like this:

```
std::string result = boost::regex_replace(str, boost::regex("a"), "b",
                                          boost::match_default | boost::format_perl);
if (result != str) {
    // Do something with "result".
}
```

However, if you feel like you need a very efficient implementation, you could use [`regex_match()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) that tells you exactly what was matched and then replace sub-strings yourself.